# Math class functionality in cn1

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to calculate the distance between 2 GPS coordinates for very short distances. I have found a few methods but they all require methods of the math class. My aim is to implement an algorithm such as this:

```
     public static double haversine(
        double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2) {
    int r = 6371; // average radius of the earth in km
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
    double dLon = Math.toRadians(lng2 - lng1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
       Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) 
      * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    double d = r * c;
    return d;
}
```

I know how to convert between degrees and radians. Is there a way to calculate this in cn1 and or is there a way to use more math functions than what MathUtil offers such as sin cos and tan functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a static utility method in MapComponent that doing exactly that:

```
public static long distance(double latitude1, double longitude1, double latitude2, double longitude2) {
    double latitudeSin = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(latitude2 - latitude1) / 2);
    double longitudeSin = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(longitude2 - longitude1) / 2);
    double a = latitudeSin * latitudeSin
            + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(latitude1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(latitude2)) * longitudeSin * longitudeSin;
    double c = 2 * MathUtil.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    return (long) (6378137 * c);
}
```

Comment: Hi Chen thank you so much for your reply. I did see that method in the cn1 API document but when I typed out the method the method hints in Netbeans did not show it so I thought I was missing something. It is working great though! May I also ask you how it is that that method can make use of methods of the math class? As far as I understood the Math class is not as as portable as MathUtil which is why you could not use the Math class.

Comment: Yes. Notice it's in the com.codename1.util package.